# rename_column deletes all content of the columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

Hi I have got a rails migration problem:

When I run a migration like this:

```
class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :users, :hotel_stars, :rating_stars
    rename_column :users, :restaurant_stars, :price_stars
  end
end
```

and do a rake db:migrate it works fine. The columns are renamed and the data of those columns is in there. But when I then do a rake db:drop, create, migrate the columns are renamed and the data of those columns is gone... (One of my migration files fills the data base and it also fills those two columns before they get renamed)

What's the problem here?

Another question: I know its not a good idea to change former migration files, but is that ok when I run rake db:drop db:create and db:migrate afterwards - or will that cause problems?

The order of my migration files is the following:

add_devise_to_users -> creates a table users

add_columns_to_default_user -> adds columns and updates the whole table

```
class AddColumnsToDefaultUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
    add_column :users, :dob, :date
    add_column :users, :address, :string
    add_column :users, :hotel_stars, :integer
    add_column :users, :restaurant_stars, :integer
    add_column :users, :profile_picture_url, :string
    add_column :users, :selected_car, :integer

    User.reset_column_information

    User.find(1).update_attributes!( :name => 'Alexander MacDonald', :dob => '1984-08-20', :address => '900 Highschool Way, Mountain View, CA 94041', :hotel_stars => '3', :restaurant_stars => '2', :profile_picture_url => 'user1.png', :selected_car => 1)

  end
end
```

and then rename_column

```
class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :users, :hotel_stars, :rating_stars
    rename_column :users, :restaurant_stars, :price_stars
  end
end
```

Comment: If you drop the database, of course the data is gone.

Comment: One of my migration files fills the database and fills those two columns aswell. But after the renaming the data of those two columns is gone

Comment: I think you should use seed.rb to fill in a database, and use rake db:setup to create and feed it. It's not a trouble doing your way but I think it's more correct.

Answer (score 1):

**When you do `db:drop` you're erasing your DB.**

So, when you do that the data is wiped. That data isn't going into a temporary place to be re-inserted. If you want to retain the data that's in the DB before/after a `db:drop` you need to store it somewhere and re-insert it yourself.

When you're changing structure only, unless you have a specific reason to remove the data that's in there already, all you need to do is the `db:migrate`.

Alternatively you can use something like [populator](https://github.com/ryanb/populator) in order to empty/fill you DB with test data following a migration.

Comment: I know that the data gets erased, but one of my migration files fills the table (works!), but after the rename of two columns, those two columns are empty...

Comment: And does the migration that fills the table (1) take into account that the columns have been renamed, and (2) run AFTER the `db:drop`?

Comment: The migration file that fills the table's content doesn't know about the new column names, of course. And changing code in old migration files is not how migrations work, right? so I didn't change anything to that migration file that fills the columns. But you can review the order in my question on top. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh, I see, I see, and you're right - based on that description alone, it should be fine. So there's something we're missing. There are essentially two approaches here. (1) do some kind of output in your migrations to see when the data goes missing (or if it's never inserted for some reason) or (2) don't modify/drop/re-run migrations - if you need to change something just make a new migration. There is some conflict in the community over which approach is correct (some believe that ALL migrations should be reversable), while others prefer to simply to `db:schema:load`, and use seed files.

Comment: I think you're only hope here is debug output on your migrations to see why your data is going missing. Maybe, for some reason, it's no longer getting inserted in the first place, or maybe it's there and then disappears. I would double-check your assumptions that it's actually getting properly inserted before going further. Also, to answer another question in your original post, yes, I would say it's a really bad idea to modify previous migrations. Make a new migration instead. Changing a migration somewhere in the middle of the chain is just going to complicate things.

Comment: As some state it, generally you don't ever want to roll back (or even re-run your migrations from the beginngin), it's easier, and usually safer, to write a **new** migration to fix a problem, and always roll **forward.** This is why migrations which load data into the DB are generally avoided, and `seeds.rb` or some other method is used instead. It just breaks too easily.

Comment: Yep, it breaks very easily. Unfortunately I still don't know the solution to my problem. But I programmed a workaround with a seed (and in the future I will never touch older migrations/insert data in them ;) )